# Sumif & Vlookup combination

Tags: excel, sum, vlookup

I am trying to do the following, and I cant figure out the correct order for the vlookup and sumif.

I should start by outlining what I have. On sheet1 I have a list of ID's (1-60ish, with some variations) in column A, and each ID has a mass (as in kilos) associated with it in column B. Depending on a set of criteria that has been defined, some of the masses relate to each other and need to be summed. How they relate is outline on sheet2 as a matrix. All the IDs go down the first column and across the top column, and where they relate, and as such should be summed, a "Y" is put in the corresponding cell. Finally in sheet3 I have the list of ID's once again in column A, and I would like to lookup the row that the ID is in on the matrix on sheet2, and sum the masses from sheet1 where there is a "Y" in the matrix.

For example (illustrated in screenshot), the formula in column B of sheet3, looks up ID 26 in column C of sheet2 (shown) to identify which IDs should be summed (denoted by a "Y" and relating to the IDs in row 3) to calculate the combined mass. The masses that need to be summed from sheet1 are related to ID 23, 25, 26. So the output required is the sum of masses 23, 25, 26.

I have attached a screenshot to make this clearer.

[image: Mass Matrix]

I hope someone can help!

Comment: Are all your sheets using the same rows? Do the values on sheet1 Row 10 match the values on Sheet2, and 3? As in are all the headers lined up?

Comment: I didn't realize you didn't tag this with VBA, and I provided a solution in VBA. If you can use VLookup, that would be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

UNTESTED (might be worth your reading [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) but please try:

```
=SUMIF(INDIRECT("Sheet2!"&MATCH(VLOOKUP(A4,Sheet1!A:B,2,0),Sheet2!A:A,0)&":"&MATCH(VLOOKUP(A4,Sheet1!A:B,2,0),Sheet2!A:A,0)),"Y",Sheet2!1:1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using VBA.  Didn't see there wasn't a tag for it. This is untested, as I don't have your matrix to work with.

**Setup:**

- This is dependent on the "Masses" listed on Sheet3 being in the same order, and on the same row numbers as Sheet2.
- Place this sub in a module.

**What happens:**

1. Initialize Variables, Sheet Names, Last Rows, etc
2. Loop through Sheet 3 by Rows, holding the place to insert the sum
3. Loop through the columns on Sheet2, searching for "Y"
4. IF a "Y", get `tempMass` from Row3 of that column
5. Loop through Sheet1 by Rows, searching for `tempMass`
6. IF Match is found, add mass to `tempSum`
7. Repeat 3-6 for every column on Sheet2
8. Set value on Sheet3 current row, Column B to tempSum
9. Repeat 2-9

**Code:**

```
Sub SumMasses()

Dim lastRow1 As Long, lastRow2 As Long, lastRow3 As Long, lastCol As Long
Dim s1Row As Long, s2Row As Long, s3Row As Long, lCol As Long
Dim s1 As String, s2 As String, s3 As String, tempMass As String
Dim tempSum As Double

s1 = "Sheet1"       'Define Sheet names here
s2 = "Sheet2"
s3 = "Sheet3"

lastRow1 = Sheets(s1).Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
lastRow2 = Sheets(s2).Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
lastRow3 = Sheets(s3).Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
lastCol = Sheets(s2).Cells(3, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).column  'Get last Column from matrix on Sheet 2, Row 3

    For s3Row = 4 To lastRow3
        tempSum = 0

        'Loop through columns on Matrix to find "Y"
        For lCol = 4 To lastCol
            If Sheets(s2).Cells(s3Row, lCol) = "Y" Then
                tempMass = Sheets(s2).Cells(3, lCol)        'Get Mass from row 3 above match

                'Loop through Sheet 1 to find Mass to add to sum
                For s1Row = 4 To lastRow1
                    If Sheets(s1).Cells(s1Row, "A") = tempMass Then
                        tempSum = Sheets(s1).Cells(s1Row, "B")
                    End If
                Next s1Row
            End If
        Next lCol   'Advance through the columns

        Sheets(s3).Cells(s3Row, "B") = tempSum      'Set sum on Sheet 3

    Next s3Row      'Proceed to the next Mass on Sheet3

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjust ranges to suit:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$31,INDEX((INDEX(Sheet2!$D$4:$AG$33,MATCH(Sheet3!A2,Sheet2!$C$4:$C$33,0),0)="Y")*(Sheet2!$D$3:$AG$3)+1,)-1,Sheet1!$B$2:$B$31))
```